# Radar/Spider Chart with Curved edges in iOS (Swift 5)

Tags: ios, graph, swift5, uibezierpath, radar-chart

I am trying to create a spider/radar chart in iOS (Swift 5) with curved edges. I used `UIBezierPath` to create the basic spider chart and tried using `addQuadCurve` function to add curves to the edges of the path. The Solution however didn't work out. I also tried to create curves between two points instead of the line but the end result was completely different.

Need your help to get the end result as in the attachments. Attaching current and expected versions (Left is the current version I designed and Right is what is expected).

[image]

Comment: Show your code what you have tried so far ?